# Rspec tests for CLI tool. User input simulation

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have function, which i need to cover tests. function looks like

```
def foo
  system 'bar'
end
```

And `foo` wait for user input, which i have to provide. How I can provide user input?

PS: I need it under Ubuntu.

Comment: How are you running foo? As a method call from inside the test?

Comment: Also, what platform? Hacking stdin will be a lot easier on a UNIX.

Comment: Platform Ubuntu. `foo` is runnung like unit test and I need to get only the summary of `foo`, but i have no problem with it.

Comment: Is this a unit test, or an integration test?  If you're unit testing, then I suggest stubbing 'system', if you're integration testing then you might need to look into manipulating stdin and stdout

Comment: It is an integration test, so, I can not stub it. So, if I understend you right you suggest to do somethinng like `$stdin.write "\n"`, but I get the error, `IOError: not opened for writing`.